# How to get value of next input in <td> which is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append data to `tbody` which I get through ajax request. In backend I print data like this

```
echo "<tr>
        <td><input type='text'  name='sl_p_codes[]' id='p_code' value='{$data['p_code']}' ></td>
        <td><input type='text'  name='sl_products[]' id='qty' value='{$data['p_name']}' ></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='product_qty' name='sl_p_qty[]'  id='qt' value='01' size='2'></td>
        <td><input type='hidden'  name='sl_unit_cost[]'  id='product_unit_price'></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='product_total_cost' readonly name='sl_price[]' id='qty' value='{$data['p_price']}' ></td>
        <td class='center'><a href='#'  onclick='delrow(this);' class='btn btn-danger'>X</a></td>
    </tr>";
```

If I change `id='product_qty'`(input field) the value of `id='product_total_cost'` (input field) should be updated with the value of `id='product_unit_price'`

Comment: That sounds like you know what you need, I suggest you start doing it. StackOverflow is not the site where you write specifications and others write the code for you. Show what you have written so far and describe exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I am not getting output to input field which has id product_total_cost

Comment: Please read my comment again. Pay attention to the last sentence.

Comment: A row contains 4 input fields 1st field contains Product code, 2nd field contains product name 3rd field contains no of product and 4th input contains product cost. I want , If I change no of product the product cost should be updated with no of product X unit cost (which is in hidden input tad).

Comment: You keep repeating what you want and do not show a single line of your own code. That's not how this works. I understand what you want. *You* must still write the code.

Comment: It is solved ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```js
$("#product_qty").on("change", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find("#product_total_cost").val(
    (parseFloat($(this).closest("tr").find("#product_unit_price").val()) * parseInt($(this).val())).toFixed(2)
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='sl_p_codes[]' id='p_code' value='ABC011'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='sl_products[]' id='qty' value='01'></td>
    <td><input type='number' id='product_qty' name='sl_p_qty[]' id='qt' value='01' size='2'></td>
    <td><input type='hidden' name='sl_unit_cost[]' id='product_unit_price' value="1.00"></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='product_total_cost' readonly name='sl_price[]' id='qty' value='1.00'></td>
    <td class='center'><a href='#' onclick='delrow(this);' class='btn btn-danger'>X</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I change 2nd input field it should be like this 4th input value = 2nd input value X 3rd input value.

Comment: You can modify it to suit your needs.